# Wordpress: Move entry-title

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

There has been something that i can't seem to work out. I's about an entry title, which on the front page shows on top of each portfolio item (on hover).

Here you can see what i mean; [www.untoldworks.com](http://www.untoldworks.com)

All i'm trying to do is move the entry title so it shows in line with the entry category & entry date on the left side of the portfolio item.

As i understand the entry meta layout for the portfolio page is found within template-tags.php

```
function eris_entry_header() {

if ( !is_single() && ( !is_search() && ( 'link' == get_post_format() || 'quote' == get_post_format() ) ) ) {
    return;
}

$time_string = '<time class="entry-date published updated" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';

if ( get_the_time( 'U' ) !== get_the_modified_time( 'U' ) ) {
    $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time><time class="updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time>';
}

$edit_post_link = '';

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $edit_post_link = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_edit_post_link() ) . '"></a>';
}

$time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_date() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_modified_date() )
);

$posted_on = sprintf(
    esc_html_x( '%s', 'post date', 'eris' ),
    '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $time_string . '</a>'
);

if ( 'portfolio' == get_post_type() ) {
    $categories_list = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'ct_portfolio', '', '&nbsp;', '' );
} else {
    $categories_list = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'category', '', '&nbsp;', '' );
}

if ( is_single() ) {
    the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
} else {
    the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
}

printf( '<div class="entry-meta"><span class="category-list">%1$s</span><span class="post-date">%2$s</span><span class="edit-link">%3$s</span></div>', $categories_list, $posted_on, $edit_post_link );}
```

It would be great if the entry title would show first (so left bottom corner of portfolio item) after that the entry category and after that the date.

Hope someone can figure this out XD
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So all you need is to show entry title with category and date?

Comment: Yes that's the plan but i can't seem to figure out how..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer / Final Update:**

From the code you posted, it seems that the last line is the relevant one:

```
printf( '<div class="entry-meta"><span class="category-list">%1$s</span><span class="post-date">%2$s</span><span class="edit-link">%3$s</span></div>', $categories_list, $posted_on, $edit_post_link );}
```

You will need to add a new argument and use argument swapping.
Try replacing this line with this:

```
// use 'get_the_title()' instead of 'the_title()'
$my_title = get_the_title();

// note that I added the "$my_title" to the arguments on the end of the line
// and also that I added "%4$s" to the printf() function to show our new title
printf( '<div class="entry-meta">%4$s<span class="category-list">%1$s</span><span class="post-date">%2$s</span><span class="edit-link">%3$s</span></div>', $categories_list, $posted_on, $edit_post_link, $my_title );}
```

You can find more info and explanation regarding `printf()` on the official codex page [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Placeholders).

For a better explaination look at this example:

```
$city = 'New York';
$zipcode = '12345';

printf( 'Your city is %1$s, and your zip code is %2$s.', $city, $zipcode );
```

will become:

"Your city is *New York*, and your zip code is *12345*."

---

**Update: (before using get_the_title() )**

I can see in your sourcecode that the new element with the title is added on the wrong place, right before the entry-meta container.

In the source code you see this:

```
<span class="post-date">Stefan Rustenburg</span> // this is our post-title
<div class="entry-meta">
    <span class="post-date"></span> // this seems to be an empty element ?!
    <span class="category-list"></span>
    <span class="post-date"></span>
    <span class="edit-link"></span>
</div>
```

If I change the code to this:

```
<div class="entry-meta">
    <span class="post-date">Stefan Rustenburg</span> // this is our post-title
    <span class="post-date"></span> // this seems to be an empty element ?!
    <span class="category-list"></span>
    <span class="post-date"></span>
    <span class="edit-link"></span>
</div>
```

The title get added to the right place.
See: 
[image: post-title on right place]

Did you create the `span` element with the class `post-date` yourself?
How is your `printf()` function currently looking?

P.S.
<del>Maybe also try using `the_title()` without `before` and `after`, to see if that change something.</del>

As you are using printf() maybe you need to use `get_the_title()` instead of `the_title()`.

Comment: Hi LWS-Mo, Thanks for the reply. I've implemented your code, and this is something along the lines i tried myself. But the strange thing is that the title still prints on top of the portfolio item. Even when i apply the same css as the date or the category. See result of code: [link](http://untoldworks.com) Am i not seeing some css that's responsible?

Comment: I had a look with the developer tools an the website. It seems that the newly created title element is added at the wrong place. See my updated answer above.

Comment: it's strange that the new title element is placed outside the div, because if you look at the printf() function it should be inside. `printf( '<div class="entry-meta">%4$s<span class="category-list">%1$s</span><span class="post-date">%2$s</span><span class="edit-link">%3$s</span></div>', $categories_list, $posted_on, $edit_post_link, $my_title );` Also tried using the_title() without anything else but then it just doesn't show up.

Comment: Also to answer your question about the post-date, this is not my code, it came with the Eris template. I also thought it was strange that the time code  was so overly present.

Comment: Did you also tried using `get_the_title()` instead of `the_title()` ?

Comment: When i use `$my_title = get_the_title( '<span class="category-list">', '</span>' );` in stead of `$my_title = the_title( '<span class="category-list">', '</span>' );` the title also doesn't show up at all.

Comment: oh wait!! it worked!! the `get_the_title()` did the trick when i use it witout the `<span>` in there. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Yes, `get_the_title()` dont have before and after arguments, just the post ID argument. But you could add a new span element in the `printf()` function. (`...<span class="anything">%4$s</span>...`)

Sorry about the back and forth, I will edit my answer to highlight the `get_the_title()`.

Please vote for my answer if it helped you.